# object values won't show

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got data like this in postman

```
"emails": "{\"1\": \"help@me.com\", \"2\": \"help2@help.com\", \"3\": \"please@helpme.com\"}",
```

so i iterated through the objects but I ain't getting the value. what am I doing wrong here? How do I get the emails only?

```
<span v-for="(item, key, index, value) in data.item.emails" :key="key">
              {{value}}
            </span>
```

Comment: i looks like a bad attempt at JSON ... or JSON within JSON ... - once fixed, definitely won't have item, key index and value ...

Comment: Eww, double-encoded JSON. Fix your API (or tell the maintainers to do so)

Answer (score 1):

The format is in string. You should parse it to object using `JSON.parse()`, and iterate through the object's values using `Object.values()`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    data: {
      item: {
        emails: "{\"3\": \"help@me.com\", \"104\": \"help2@help.com\", \"146\": \"please@helpme.com\"}"
      }
    }
  }

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span v-for="(item, key) in Object.values(JSON.parse(data.item.emails))" :key="key">
    {{ item }}<br/>
   </span>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need `Object.values()`. Vue's `v-for` can iterate objects just fine and that way, you won't lose those object keys (`3`, `104`, `146`, etc)

Comment: @Phil can you please explain why we can lose object ? I cant get it, thanks!

Comment: @ChauGiang `Object.values()` turns the object values into an array and discards the keys

Comment: Yes, but you said use Object.values we can lose keys, how come @Phil